# Extra child process hangs various apps

Tags: 16.04, process, opengl

Ubuntu Studio 16.04, Lenovo laptop.

*Sometimes* when I launch an application from (1) the main application menu, or (2) right click on a file ("Open with..."), or (3) command line, the application hangs.
(The hanging application has been: Firefox, Thunderbird, LibreOffice.)

Poking around the process tree, I discover that in all cases, the requested application has spawned a child process.  Example:

```
~$ ps aux | grep thunderbird
jga       7420  2.2  2.5 618832 99864 ?        Sl   22:24   0:00 /usr/lib/thunderbird/thunderbird
jga       7424  0.1  0.7 378240 31344 ?        S    22:24   0:00 /usr/lib/thunderbird/thunderbird
jga       7452  0.0  0.0  14224   928 pts/1    S+   22:24   0:00 grep thunderbird
```

(And pstree confirms the parent-child relationship between 7420 and 7424.)

If I kill the child process, the parent then starts up normally.

Here's Libre Office doing the same thing.

```
~$ libreoffice --calc &
[2] 7792
[1]   Done                    libreoffice --calc
~$ #hanging...
~$ ps aux | grep office
jga       7792  0.1  0.1 207860  5764 pts/1    Sl   22:52   0:00 /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/oosplash --calc
jga       7809  0.4  1.4 607036 58752 pts/1    Sl   22:52   0:00 /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin --calc --splash-pipe=5
jga       7810  0.0  0.6 406804 24200 pts/1    S    22:52   0:00 /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin --calc --splash-pipe=5
jga       7815  0.0  0.0  14224  1028 pts/1    S+   22:53   0:00 grep office
~$ kill -9 7810
~$ # Spreadsheet comes up.
```

However, if I start the process in the foreground - no hang.

So what's going on?  The only system modification I've made recently was to add Notes to my Panel, which I later removed again.

Wheeling out the toolbox, I ran strace on both firefox and libreoffice.
e.g. `strace -ff -o /tmp/loffice libreoffice --calc`

In both cases, the hanging subprocesses had the following feature in common:

- opening /etc/drirc for read
- checking for the existence of ~/.drirc (it doesn't exist)
- a syscall writing to some handle that ends up hanging, e.g.

  ```
  ioctl(5, DRM_IOCTL_I915_GEM_CREATE, 0x7ffd90290680) = 0
  ioctl(5, _IOC(_IOC_READ|_IOC_WRITE, 0x64, 0x5e, 0x28), 0x7ffd90290630) = 0
  ioctl(5, DRM_IOCTL_I915_GEM_SET_DOMAIN, 0x7ffd90290630) = 0
  ioctl(5, DRM_IOCTL_I915_GEM_SET_DOMAIN <unfinished ...>
  ```

A quick trip to the Goog tells me that drirc is related to rendering, and I'm reminded that my brief install of the Notes Panel app was the first time I'd seen semitransparent windows in this install.

So, related?  What's going on?